# How to check if nullable boolean is not true?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Righ now I have this that works, but its ugly and long:

```
        var details = dc.SunriseShipment
            .Where(it => (it.isDeleted == null || it.isDeleted == false));
```

Is there a better way to do this? I tried "it.isDeleted != true" and "it.isDeleted ?? false == false" but they are not working.

Comment: "they are not working" doesn't tell us what you've observed vs what you expected...

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: The rowcount does not change

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
.Where(it => !(it.isDeleted ?? false));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an GetValueOrDefault method which returns a default value when the value is null:

```
var details = dc.SunriseShipment
.Where(it => !it.isDeleted.GetValueOrDefault(false));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Where(it => it.isDeleted == (bool?)false);
```

Comment: 9 seconds, not bad :)